# RSS feed/email list to be notified about java updates

Tags: oracle, update, java

I'm doing upgrades of JDK on our servers regularly. But because Oracle JDK installed via custom packages (not via package manager) I need way to be notified about updates.

Are there way to be notified about java (JDK) updates? RSS (preferred) or email list? 
I've found so far:

- [Java SE News](https://blogs.oracle.com/javase/) - exactly what I need, but it's dormant
- [Oracle Security Alerts](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/rss-otn-sec.xml) - contains only security updates

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to Critical Patch Update Alert E-mails:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/securityemail-090378.html